# Kohana upgrade 2.4 from 2.3.4

Tags: php, kohana, upgrade, kohana-2

My version 2.3.4 How can i upgrade Kohana to 2.4? I looked this link but can't help me.

http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/upgrading

Comment: I found this http://ryansnyder.tumblr.com/post/613194200/upgrading-kohana-2-3-to-2-4. It can be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no stable release for **2.4**, its an unsupported branch. **2.3.4** was the last one in **2.x** branch. You should upgrade to **3.0**.